# How do I scale a graphviz diagram in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz, dot

I have a GraphViz diagram embedded in Sphinx, such as

```
.. graphviz::
   :caption: My diagram

   digraph {
        a -> b -> c -> d
   }
```

How do I scale it for display in the HTML generated by Sphinx?  It doesn't accept a :scale: directive after the :caption:, so I would need to do something inside the Graphviz.  However, Graphviz guides usually leave scaling to command line arguments for "dot".

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I just figured it out.  There is a size="x,y" directive where size is in printed inches, so:

```
.. graphviz::
   :caption: My diagram

   digraph {
        size="4,4";
        a -> b -> c -> d
   }
```